# Deeper routing makes build.js file invisible for a web app (Vue2 + Webpack2)

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Trying to configure routing in my Single-Page App, I encountered a strange behavior. When routes are at the same level as the root (e.g. *localhost:8080/contact*, *localhost:8080/user*), copying and pasting URLs works perfectly. However, when I get deeper into the structure (like: *localhost:8080/user/dorothy* or *localhost:8080/user/peter*), pasting such URL results in 404 error in the console: `build.js` cannot be found.

My `webpack.config.js` has the following entries:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: './src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/'),
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
(...)
}
```

Routes are defined as:

```
const routes = [
  {path: '/user/:user', component: Users},
  {path: '/contact', component: Contact},
  {path: '/', component: Home}
];
```

As you see, bundled script is served from `./dist/build.js` file. How should I configure it to make it visible for deeper routes?

Comment: Please post your routes.

Comment: Edit: added them to the question.

Comment: Your path says /users/:user and question says /user/peter. Is that a typo?

Comment: Corrected that. "peter" as a user name is passed dynamically. No matter which user name is displayed, there are always missing resources when pasting URL or refreshing browser's window.

Comment: How are you serving this? Node server or any other?

Comment: Yes, it's on node.js.

Comment: Would need full webpack config, main.js, app.vue and your index.html to recreate this or may be a fiddle.

Comment: I'd read through here: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html

Comment: @BillCriswell: removal of "mode: history" did the thing! Please add it as the answer.